# Pointer Cancellation up reversal

Tags: accessibility

I want to know what is up reversal in Wcag 2.5.2 pointer cancellation.i got some information but doesn’t provide a clear understanding.
Up reversal: mouse hover on a button or link it shows tool tip and moves the moves away tool tip disappears. I don’t understand exactly. Could you please clarify me and any example site for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Up reversal" refers to a scenario where a user moves the pointer (e.g. mouse cursor) over an element on a webpage (such as a button or link), causing a tooltip or other additional information to appear. The issue arises when the user then moves the pointer away from the element, but the tooltip or additional information remains visible on the page.

This can be problematic for users with certain disabilities, such as those who rely on assistive technologies or who have difficulty controlling their mouse movements. It can make it difficult for them to interact with the page and can cause confusion or frustration.

To comply with WCAG 2.5.2 Pointer Cancellation, it is important to ensure that any additional information that appears on mouse hover disappears when the mouse pointer moves away from the element. This can be achieved using various techniques, such as using JavaScript to detect when the pointer has moved away from the element and hiding the tooltip or additional information accordingly.

Here's an example of how "up reversal" could be an issue on a website:

Let's say there is a navigation menu with several links, and each link has a tooltip that appears when the mouse is hovered over it. If a user with a disability that affects their mouse control accidentally moves the mouse pointer over one of the links, they may unintentionally trigger the tooltip. If the tooltip doesn't disappear when they move the pointer away, it could obscure other parts of the page or interfere with their ability to interact with the page in other ways.

To avoid this issue, the website could use JavaScript to ensure that the tooltip disappears when the user moves the pointer away from the link. This would ensure that the page is accessible to users with disabilities and would comply with WCAG 2.5.2 Pointer Cancellation.

Comment: Thank you so much :) can you please provide any example website for more clarity.

Comment: "https://www.homedepot.com/" 
In this website hover over "Specials & Offers". A menu will appear. Now move the mouse pointer to "My Account" or any other area above it. The menu remains open.

Comment: Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Criterion 2.5.2 Pointer Cancellation is not about hover events, but about down and up events (when a single pointer is depressed or released).

[Understanding SC 2.5.2](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/pointer-cancellation.html) gives additional explanations about Up Reversal.
One possible example of Up Reversal: a behaviour will be triggered as long as you press a button (down event), but it will stop (be reversed) when you release the pointer from the button (up event). Up Reveral shares similarities with Abort or Undo, but is different to some extend. Up Reversal is not about undoying a task or functionality, but more about reversing the outcome.

Criterion 2.5.2 Pointer Cancellation must not be mixed up with 1.4.13 Content on Hover or Focus.